# Must declare the scalar variable @param problem

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, sqlcommand

Newbie alert!

Error:

`Must declare the scalar variable "@param2".`

Must declare the scalar variable "@param2"

(twice for two param2's)

`protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlDataSource ds1 = new SqlDataSource(GetConnectionString(), GetSelectionString());
   GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}`

and

```
 protected string GetSelectionString()
    {
        string SearchString = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "ALL")
        {
            SqlParameter @param2 = new SqlParameter();
            SqlCommand SearchAll = new SqlCommand("SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details WHERE (Document_Id IN (SELECT Document_Id FROM Search_Index WHERE (Tag_Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Tag_Id FROM Tags WHERE (Tag_Name LIKE '%'+@param2+'%'))))) UNION SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details AS Document_Details_1 WHERE (Document_Name LIKE '%'+@param2+'%')");
           SearchAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", SearchString.ToString());
            return (string)SearchAll.CommandText.ToString();
        }
```

TextBox1 value will be passed by user. I have searched solutions for around 6 hours... and still stuck up with this problem. Any solutions please?

Using VS2008 with MS SQL server 2008 R2 connection.

**EDIT1: GIVING THE COMPLETE CODE.::**

protected string GetSelectionString()
    {
        string SearchString = "%";
        SearchString = SearchString+ TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToString();
        SearchString =SearchString+ "%";

```
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "ALL")
    {
        SqlParameter @param2 = new SqlParameter();
        SqlCommand SearchAll = new SqlCommand("SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details WHERE (Document_Id IN (SELECT Document_Id FROM Search_Index WHERE (Tag_Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Tag_Id FROM Tags WHERE (Tag_Name LIKE @param2))))) UNION SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details AS Document_Details_1 WHERE (Document_Name LIKE @param2)");
        SearchAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", SearchString.ToString());
        return (string)SearchAll.CommandText.ToString();
    }
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "FILENAMES")
    {
        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();

        SqlCommand SearchFileName = new SqlCommand("SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details WHERE (Document_Name LIKE @param2)");
        SearchFileName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", SearchString.ToString());
        return (string)SearchFileName.CommandText.ToString();
    }
```

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource ds1 = new SqlDataSource(GetConnectionString(), GetSelectionString());
        GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

please note: I am binding it to a GridView control. This WORKS if I hardcode the value of the @param2 in the query.

**EDIT2: A DIFFERENT APPROACH WITH DIFFERENT ERROR:**

`tried it this way, 
SqlCommand temp1 = GetSelectionString();
string temp2 = temp1.CommandText.ToString();
SqlDataSource ds1 = new SqlDataSource(GetConnectionString(), temp1.ToString());
GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
GridView1.DataBind();`

....getting new error

Could not find server 'System' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find server 'System' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: Yes it works if you **hard-code** your value - but it will **NEVER** work if you want to make the parameter configurable.

Comment: Updated my answer yet again - tried to provide a full solution. Adapt as needed.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I tried adapting your solution. But the same error... param not declared. I am giving up on injection. I will do manual term checking and removing all non alphanumeric. Thanks anyway to everyone who helped me learn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `@param2` as a "stand-alone" parameter - do **not** pack it into a string!

```
SqlCommand SearchAll = new SqlCommand(
   "SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details 
    WHERE (Document_Id IN 
       (SELECT Document_Id FROM Search_Index 
        WHERE (Tag_Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Tag_Id 
                          FROM Tags 
                          WHERE Tag_Name LIKE @param2)))) 
    UNION 
    SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details AS Document_Details_1 
    WHERE Document_Name LIKE @param2");
```

If you want to search for a string with `%` at the beginning and end, you need to supply that into the value of `@param2`

Also: your query might work a lot better if you break up those subselects and use a single SQL statement using JOIN's to join together the tables...

**Update:** your approach has a very basic flaw: you seem to expect that if you use a parametrized query in the `SqlCommand` you'll get out the full SQL statement with the parameter value filled in when accessing the `SearchAll.CommandText` - that is simply not the case - the parameter `@param2` will **not** be substituted with its value!

So basically, you cannot do this the way you're doing it right now - what you need to do is pass back a `SqlCommand` instance - **not** just a string! That will **never** work

**Update #2:** you need to do something like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // grab search string from web UI
   string searchString = "%" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "%";

   // get connection string
   string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

   SqlDataSource ds1 = new SqlDataSource(connectionString);

   // get the SqlCommand to do your SELECT
   ds1.SelectCommand = GetSelectCommand(connectionString, searchString);

   GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

and

```
protected SqlCommand GetSelectCommand(string connectionString, string searchValue)
{
   // define query string - could be simplified!
   string queryStmt = "SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details WHERE (Document_Id IN (SELECT Document_Id FROM Search_Index WHERE (Tag_Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Tag_Id FROM Tags WHERE Tag_Name LIKE @param2)))) UNION SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details AS Document_Details_1 WHERE Document_Name LIKE @param2";

   // set up a SqlCommand based on the query string and the connection string passed in       
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, connectionString);

   // define parameter
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

   // set value for parameter
   cmd.Parameters["@param2"].Value = searchValue;

   // pass back SqlCommand to fill the data source
   return cmd;
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Does not work either :( Sent an input like "%hello%" to the @param2. Even then the same error.

Comment: @Ranjanmano: your approach is fundamentally flawed - you cannot expect the SqlCommand's `.CommandText` to contain the actual SQL statement with the parameter value filled in - it doesn't work that way in ADO.NET ! You need to pass back the `SqlCommand` object and use that - do not rely on a string!

Comment: tried it this way, 
SqlCommand temp1 = GetSelectionString();
string temp2 = temp1.CommandText.ToString();
SqlDataSource ds1 = new SqlDataSource(GetConnectionString(), temp1.ToString());
GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
GridView1.DataBind();
....getting new error
Could not find server 'System' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers
Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers

Comment: as per docs/samples available using %+@param should be perfectly usable  SELECT * FROM Catalog 
WHERE Description LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'   The other alternative is to add %XX% before sending the parameter over such a

Comment: Solved using the connection string name as the connection string and then assign it to the declared SqlConnection

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I ran across it when trying to remember how to accomplish this same thing and I have a solution.  Now that I read Sai Kalyan Akshinthala's most recent answer, I think he might have been hinting at the same thing.

The key is that when you add the parameter to the SQLDataSource's parameter collection, you need to leave the "@" off of the name.  The error is stating that it doesn't see a parameter with the correct name to match the one passed in the SQL parameterized string.  While the SQL parameter in the string must be named with "@", the matching SQLDataSource parameters should not use it.

Here is my C# code.  It is a method used behind a web form that provides a flexible search of an article database.

```
protected void CreateArticleSearch()
{
    // Declare the base query and start the WHERE clause.
    string articleQuery = "SELECT DisplayTitle, Summary, CreateDate, ArticleID FROM Articles ";
    string whereClause = "WHERE ";

    try
    {
        // Important, clear the parameters first.
        Articles.SelectParameters.Clear();

        // Test the field to see if there's anything there.
        if (textTitle.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            // If there is a value, add to the WHERE clause and add a parameter.
            whereClause += "DisplayTitle LIKE @ArticleTitle ";
            Articles.SelectParameters.Add("ArticleTitle", "%" + textTitle.Text + "%");
        }

        // Do the same for each subsequent field except test to see if the
        // WHERE clause already holds something and add AND as necessary.
        if (textSummary.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            if (whereClause == "WHERE ")
                whereClause += "Summary LIKE @ArticleSummary ";
            else
                whereClause += "AND Summary LIKE @ArticleSummary ";

            Articles.SelectParameters.Add("ArticleSummary", "%" + textSummary.Text + "%");
        }

        // Test WHERE clause to see if it contains anything.
        // Add it to the base query if it does.
        if (whereClause.Length > 6)
            articleQuery += whereClause;

        // Specify the command type for the SQLDataSource and attach the query.
        Articles.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
        Articles.SelectCommand = articleQuery;

    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Then, all that remains is to to a DataBind on the GridView that's being supplied by the SQLDataSource.  I've used this in a few applications and it works great.

Andrew Comeau

Comment: I think the `@` prefix is optional IIRC. Did you try your code with it as well?

Comment: Yes. That was the final thing that I fixed to get it working. If you add a parameter to the SQLDataSource object on the page and inspect the object's markup, the parameter is named without the @.

Answer (score 2):

`you concatenating parameter to your query` that's wrong in your query

```
SqlCommand("SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details WHERE (Document_Id IN (SELECT Document_Id FROM Search_Index WHERE (Tag_Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Tag_Id FROM Tags WHERE (Tag_Name LIKE %@param2%))))) UNION SELECT Document_Name, Document_Summary FROM Document_Details AS Document_Details_1 WHERE (Document_Name LIKE %@param2%)");
```

Comment: tried this. This sends the value '%@param2%' to the database. It doesn't think of param as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

First your declaration of param2 is useless:
SqlParameter @param2 = new SqlParameter()
If you were to use it - try to make it something a lot more meaningful  such as documentName
Second - try removing one of the parameters? does it work?
if you add it a second time does it fail? if so then change the name for the second one and add it as a separate parameter.

Comment: removed the declaration also. Tried it with one parameter alone. Even then it does not work. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

You, are declaring a Parameter with name `param2` and using `@param2`, so its getting stuck up. Correct it and try.